# OSX: See bonjour computers through VPN?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, mac, share, bonjour

I use VPN to connect to my works network.  Is there a way to see those computers through bonjour once I connect?  Currently I need their IP to connect since I can't see them.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that with OpenVPN you can achieve this...

http://quintinsmits.com/2009/09/14/bonjour-mdns-via-openvpn-on-linux-with-avahi-deamon

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use [Network Beacon](http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/ProductPages/NetworkBeacon.html) to do this, although I haven't tested it personally. Googling for "bonjour proxy" turns up other possible options.